# Telerik Reporting R3 2016 SP1 Not Working In Windows Server 2012 Virtual Machine(Azure & AWS)

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-server-2012

I Deploy a Web Application on **Windows Server 2012** Virtual Machine.The UI is Working fine.But the Report is not Working.But It works fine on **localhost** and the godaddy Sever.The same code is used for all environment Please, anyone, try to help me to Resolve the Problem.